# Passing index path information to button action from cell Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button, action

I have this:

```
let mapsbut = cell.viewWithTag(912) as! UIButton
mapsbut.addTarget(self, action: "mapsHit:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

and

```
func mapsHit(){

    // get indexPath.row from cell
    // do something with it

}
```

How is this accomplished?

Comment: Inside what method is your first code snippet located?

Comment: @iosDev82 that question is in Objective C

Comment: The link posted above has some answers but another method is to assign the indexPath to a property of your custom UITableViewCell subclass when you create the custom cell. The action method could be inside the subclass and you can use a postNotification, or a delegate via protocol to indicate that the controller should take some action. You can search SO for  many specific solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the **`tag`** from your button to pass or hold a value, or a var inside of your custom cell implementation. For example, if you have your button as an `outlet` in your `UITableViewCell` (*for instance*):

```
class MenuViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titlelabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton! {
        didSet {
            button.addTarget(self, action: "mapsHit:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
          }
    }
    func mapsHit(sender: UIButton){
        let indexPathOfThisCell = sender.tag
        println("This button is at \(indexPathOfThisCell) row")
        // get indexPath.row from cell
        // do something with it

    }
}
```

Notice here, that you need to set `sender:UIButton` as a parameter when you set **"mapsHit:"**. This will be the button itself in wich the user has tapped.

Now, for this to work, your tag can not be **"912"**. Instead when you build your cell, assign to the `tag` property of your button, the value of it's `indexPath`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MenuViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MenuViewCell

        cell.titlelabel?.text = data[indexPath.row].description
        cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  You cant convert an IndexPath to an Int.

Comment: ...for this is that I do indexPath.row

Answer (score 0):

...one solution could be to have a var inside your class holding the `indexPath` of the last cell tapped, then you can use that value inside your `mapsHit()` function.